# cron & wget adding new line to each document write

Tags: cron, wget

So I am trying to create a cron job that will, on a daily basis, execute a job on a webpage.

My cron command:
    0 0 * * */1 wget -t 1 - "http://urlto.job/job9" -O ->> home/password_reset_log.txt

All of this works, however I am trying to carry out the seemingly menial task of adding a new line to each entry in the text file.

Currently I get:

```
{"error":0,"result":"Password reset email successfully sent to 0 users, 0 emails failed to send","jDateLastRun":"10 Jan 2018, 00:00:07","jHandle":"check_password_resets","jID":"9"}{"error":0,"result":"Password reset email successfully sent to 0 users, 0 emails failed to send","jDateLastRun":"10 Jan 2018, 00:00:07","jHandle":"check_password_resets","jID":"9"}
```

So all the entries are on a single line. What I want is:

```
{"error":0,"result":"Password reset email successfully sent to 0 users, 0 emails failed to send","jDateLastRun":"10 Jan 2018, 00:00:07","jHandle":"check_password_resets","jID":"9"}
{"error":0,"result":"Password reset email successfully sent to 0 users, 0 emails failed to send","jDateLastRun":"10 Jan 2018, 00:00:07","jHandle":"check_password_resets","jID":"9"}
```

So all the entries start on a new line (easier to read and see which jobs ran successfully and which failed and the result of each time the job ran).

Is there a simple way to do this (perhaps adding a parameter to my cron command).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `| xargs echo` to append the newline.

Your entry would look something like this:

```
0 0 * * */1 wget -t 1 - "http://urlto.job/job9" -O - | xargs echo >> home/password_reset_log.txt
```

Of course, this will only work if your URL always gives exactly one line each time.

Here the demo for everyone to enjoy:

```
user@host:~$ echo -n "No newline"
No newlineuser@host:~$ echo -n "With newline" | xargs echo
With newline
user@host:~$
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give a crack and if it works mark your answer

Comment: Works perfectly! Much appreciated.